# How to get quantity of simple product on configurable product page

Tags: magento2, php, configurable-product

I'm searching the way to preload quantity of each simple product on configurable product detail page.
The reason is I want to dynamically show to client "In Stock", "Out of stock" or "Only 1 left" notification for each size+color config which was selected by client.

P.S.: I used color swatches as dropdown and I saw one hidden field which was dynamically change with selected simple product ID. But then I changed to text swatch+image swatch and this field no more changing.

Can anybody show example how to implement this functionality in Magento 2?
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is to add additional data with quantity to Configurable Product JSON before creating product detail page. Then override `swatch-renderer.js` to catch clicks on swatches.

Don't forget to include `[Vendor]/[Module]/registration.php` and `[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/module.xml` to your extension

1) `[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/ConfigurableProduct/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php`

File content:

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class Configurable
{

    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;
    protected $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    // Adding Quantitites (product=>qty)
    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $quantities = [];
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);

        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
                $product->getId(),
                $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
            $quantities[$product->getId()] = $stockitem->getQty();
        }

        $config['quantities'] = $quantities;

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

2) `[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="[vendor]_configurable_product_configurable"
                type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type\Configurable"
                sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3) `[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'[Vendor]_[Module]/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

4) Copy original file `/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` to `[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

In function `_OnClick` insert before `$widget._Rebuild();` code below:

```
var errorFlag = true;
var selectedSwatch = {};

// Compare objects
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // If number of properties is different,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        // If values of same property are not equal,
        // objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we made it this far, objects
    // are considered equivalent
    return true;
}

// Foreach every attribute and check. If only one undefined (not selected) - nothing won't work
$('.swatch-attribute').each(function () {
    var $element = $(this),
        attrId = $element.attr('attribute-id'),
        optionSelected = $element.attr('option-selected');

    if(typeof optionSelected == "undefined"){
        errorFlag = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        selectedSwatch[attrId] = optionSelected;
        errorFlag = false;
    }
});

// Show stock notification to user
if(errorFlag == false){
    var allTheProducts = $widget.options.jsonConfig.index;
    $.each(allTheProducts, function(index, value) {
        if(isEquivalent(selectedSwatch, value)){
            // Quantity of selected simple product by ID
            var qty = $widget.options.jsonConfig.quantities[index];
            console.log('Simple product ID: '+index+', quantity: '+qty);

            if(qty == 1){
                $('.stock-notification').html("ONLY 1 LEFT IN STOCK");
            } else if(qty > 1){
                $('.stock-notification').html("IN STOCK");
            } else {
                $('.stock-notification').html("OUT OF STOCK");
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    $('.stock-notification').html("");
}
```

Comment: Use `Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface` for `2.3`. `$qty = $this->salable->execute($product->getSku(), 1);`